# can't deploy war file in liferay tomcat server

Tags: apache, tomcat, liferay, liferay-6

I have my .war file and I would like to deploy it in the liferay portal. I made a copy in [Liferay Home]/deploy, eclpise displayed that the war file was deployed with success but I can't find it with the Liferay UI application.

Comment: `.war` what was in the WAR file, a portlet, hook, theme etc? Which server are you talking about, tomcat, jboss etc? what does you mean by `can't find it with Liferay UI application`?

Comment: I use liferay 6.1.1. the server is tomcat.
I can't find it by the liferay web application. I mean when I click add > More I can't find it.

Comment: What's in that WAR file? You'll only find portlets on the UI in Add->More. And you'll need to have permission to do so.

Comment: Can you show me what appear on the console related to the portlet project?